# Вставить значение, если отсутсвует дата в диапазоне

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть примерно такая таблица:

```
Date         |  Value
-------------------------
01/11/2018   |  12
02/11/2018   |  14
03/11/2018   |  11
04/11/2018   |  11
05/11/2018   |  177
07/11/2018   |  13
```

Необходимо взять последние три дня с 07.11, если какой-то день отсутствует в данном диапазоне, то вставить значение в эту дату 9999. В примере выше отсутствует 06/11. В итоге должно получиться:

```
Date         |  Value
-------------------------
05/11/2018   |  177
06/11/2018   |  9999
07/11/2018   |  13
```

У меня не получается прокинуть недостающую дату с зафиксированным значеним.

Answer (score 0):

Для наглядности создаю таблицу с одной колонкой, т.к. задача сводится к поиску пробела.

```
CREATE TABLE #Datelist (DateN Datetime)

INSERT INTO #Datelist
VALUES ('2018-01-01'),('2018-01-03'),('2018-01-08'),('2018-01-14');

WITH C AS
(
    SELECT DateN AS Cur, LEAD(DateN) OVER (ORDER BY DateN) as Nxt
    FROM #Datelist
),
C2 AS
(
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY,1,cur) as [start],DATEADD(DAY,-1,Nxt) as [end]
FROM C
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,Cur,Nxt) >1
),
C3 AS
(
SELECT [start],[end] FROM C2
UNION ALL
SELECT [start]+1,[end] FROM C3 WHERE [start]<[end]
)

SELECT [start] FROM C3
ORDER BY [start]

DROP TABLE #Datelist
```

В представленном коде замените имя таблицы и наименования полей. 
Полученное пропущенное значение вставляете с необходимым значением атрибута в целевую таблицу.

**PS** Представлено решение задачи для версии MS SQL >= 2012

Подробнее о: [LEAD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**UPD** Теперь выводится список дат от начала диапазона до его конца, все работает даже если диапазонов несколько.

Comment: Так найдётся начало пробела(ов), т.е. дата `2018-01-06` в данных отсутствует и запрос её возвращает. Но если выбросить в исходных данных ещё одну соседнюю дату `2018-01-07`, то запрос её не вернёт.

Comment: Справедливое замечание, поправлю в ближайшее время

Comment: @i-one теперь все как положено.

Comment: Мудрёно как-то. И потом, в вопросе _"взять последние три дня с 07.11, если какой-то день отсутствует в данном диапазоне, то ... В примере выше отсутствует 06/11"_, но что если отсутствует 07/11 (последний день диапазона)? Можно просто взять последовательность дат в нужном диапазоне и к ней при-left-join-ить исходные данные (три дня можно даже в переменные в `values` взять, если конечно три - это не параметр).